# Edit iframe src using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Why won't my code paste my iframe src? It is just empty in HTML.

```
<iframe id="Stream" src="" class="col-sm-12" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe id="Chat" src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

```js
$('#Stream').attr("https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=" + channel, url)
$('#Chat').attr("https://www.twitch.tv/" + channel + "/chat?popout=", url)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax for calling the `attr()` method is incorrect. The first argument is the name of the attribute and the second should be the value you want to set. It's also preferred to use the `prop()` method where possible, as it would be in this case.

```
$('#Stream').prop('src', "https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=" + channel);
$('#Chat').prop('src', "https://www.twitch.tv/" + channel + "/chat?popout=");
```

[attr() method](http://api.jquery.com/attr)
[prop() method](http://api.jquery.com/prop)

Note that this may still not work correctly if the requested domain has disallowed itself to be rendered in an iframe on a third-party website using `X-Frame-Options`.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Another method to change source path of iframe.

Please check it below.

```
$('#Stream').attr("src","https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=" + channel);
$('#Chat').attr("src","https://www.twitch.tv/" + channel + "/chat?popout=");
```